# Accessing values from path-dependent type mixin

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type, self-type

Is it possible to access values in the outer trait from an inner trait mixin? i.e.:

```
trait Outer {
  val foo
  trait Inner
}

trait InnerMixin { this: Outer#Inner =>
  def bar {
    // how can I access 'foo' here? smth like Outer.this.foo
  }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you will be able to mix your InnerMixin only inside some extension of outer, maybe you could define it inside an Outer mixin,  this way

```
trait Outer {

  val foo: Int

  trait Inner
}

trait OuterMixin  { this: Outer =>

  trait InnerMixin  { this: Inner =>
    def extension = OuterMixin.this.foo
  }
}

class ActualOuter extends Outer with OuterMixin {
  val foo = 12
  class ActualInner extends Inner with InnerMixin {

  }

}
```

Note : most of the time, you do not need a self type and you can do just OuterMixin extends Outer and InnerMixin extends Inner.

Answer (score 2):

Add a field to Inner that lets you get at it's outer

```
trait Outer {
  val foo: String

  trait Inner {
    val outer = Outer.this
  }
}

trait InnerMixin { this: Outer#Inner =>
  def bar {
    outer.foo
  }
}
```